# Comparing probabilities of two predictive models

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, predictive-models

Someone has already asked this question. But it is not answered. I have 10 logistic regression models for 10 different product categories. Then i need to come up with the best product to be offered to customer based on their predicted probability score on 10 different models. The response rate is very low so i have made number of events equal to number of non-events. I have also adjusted probability of oversampling. My question - Is it correct to compare predicted probabilities? If not, how can we standardize probability so that we can compare and rank products for each customers?
Note : Response rate is different in each models.

Comment: To which question do you refer in your opening statement?